# Create Mesh from texture shader or or particle systems

Tags: mesh, shaders, fluid-simulation

Blender has algorithms to generate mesh surfaces for a fluid simulation.

[image]

Is there an API to use this algorithm with other data? For example, is it possible to mesh a surface based on a volume shader (like shown below) or based on the density of a particle system?

[image]

---

Related question - [How to create a procedural volume and use it with the new Volume to Mesh Modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201378/how-to-create-a-procedural-volume-and-use-it-with-the-new-volume-to-mesh-modifie)

---

An approach that gets close, but does not solve the question.

In Blender 2.92 there is a 'Volume to Mesh' modifier. Using it an OpenVDB volume can be converted into an isosurface. The animation below shows the result of generating a smoke simulation, saving the cache as using OpenVDB, then loading the OpenVDB and using it a reference for the 'Volume to Mesh' modifier.

[image]

What is missing is the ability to use a volume texture to do the same thing.